# Error in UseMethod("conf_mat") : no applicable method for 'conf_mat' applied to an object of class "list"

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

I am currently trying to create a TidyModel logistic regression model on a bankruptcy dataset. I've been using [Rebecca Barters](https://www.rebeccabarter.com/blog/2020-03-25_machine_learning/) guide to create the setup. This is my first model like this, so any help is appreciated.

When trying to create the conf. matrix I get the following error:
**Error in UseMethod("conf_mat") :
no applicable method for 'conf_mat' applied to an object of class "list"**

1. Can anyone help me convert this from a list? I can't seem to do it to get the conf.matrix running.
2. When running the "model_performance" line I get an *rmse* and *rsq* score, but I expected to get *accuracy* and *roc_auc*.

Thanks a lot.

This is the head of my initial data frame "debt_data":
structure(list(bankrupt = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Interest.bearing.debt.interest.rate = c(0.000725072507250725,
0.000647064706470647, 0.00079007900790079, 0.000449044904490449,
0.000686068606860686, 0.000716071607160716), total_debt_vs_total_net_worth = c(0.0212659243655332,
0.0125023937843679, 0.0212476860084444, 0.00957240171805324,
0.00514960012402083, 0.0142131516792967), debt_ratio = c(0.207576261450555,
0.171176346101521, 0.207515796474892, 0.151464764035432, 0.106509054630105,
0.180427487377936)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

This is the code:

```
debt_data <- data %>% 
  select(
    Bankrupt.,
    Interest.bearing.debt.interest.rate,
    Total.debt.Total.net.worth,
    Debt.ratio..,
  ) %>% 
  rename(
    bankrupt = Bankrupt.,
    total_debt_vs_total_net_worth = Total.debt.Total.net.worth,
    debt_ratio = Debt.ratio..
  )

set.seed(234589)
debt_split <- initial_split(debt_data, 
                             prop = 3/4)
debt_split 

debt_train <- training(debt_split)
debt_test <- testing(debt_split)

model1_cv <- vfold_cv(debt_test)

debt_recipe <- recipe(bankrupt ~
                      Interest.bearing.debt.interest.rate +
                      total_debt_vs_total_net_worth +
                      debt_ratio, 
                      data = debt_data) %>% 
                      step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
                      step_impute_knn(all_predictors())
debt_recipe

model_workflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(debt_recipe) %>%
  add_model(linear_reg())


model_fit <- model_workflow %>% 
  last_fit(debt_split)
model_fit

model_performance <- model_fit %>% collect_metrics()
model_performance

model_predictions <- model_fit %>% collect_predictions()
model_predictions

model_predictions <- model_fit %>% pull(.predictions)
model_predictions

# Conf. matrix
model_predictions %>% 
  conf_mat(truth = bankrupt, estimate = .pred_class)
```

I've tried making changes to the model and Googled around, but I can't seem to get any further.

Comment: We need a reproducible example here to understand what is happening. Also, confusion matrices are for classification models, and you use linear regression. tidymodels expects classification models to have factor-type outcome columns, so the model fit should fail if that were the case.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: To add on to @Isaiah's comment, the [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) package will change your life.

Comment: I have added the data from the dput(head(debt_data)) in the question now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: For your second question, this follows for Topedo's observation: As you are doing a regression, you won't get accuracy or roc_auc, as these are classification measures.

Comment: I wonder if you want bankruptcy to be a factor? `library(forcats)
as_factor(debt_data$bankrupt)`

Comment: You would then add a model specification: `logistic_reg_glm_spec <-
  logistic_reg() |>
  set_engine('glm') |>
  set_mode("classification")`

Comment: And update the workflow: `model_workflow <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(debt_recipe) %>%
  add_model(logistic_reg_glm_spec)`

Comment: and fit: `fit(model_workflow, data = debt_data)`

Comment: Your select and rename steps are no longer needed in your codes, as your posted data is already transformed.

Answer (score 1):

Ulrik, your code with some changes:

1. Used mtcars data to give a reproducible example.
2. Conversion of bankrupt to factor, so you can classify.
3. Full model specification, including set to classify.
4. Removal of conversion of model_predictions to list, as conf_mat takes a tibble (this removes the error).

   ```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(tidymodels)
    debt_data <- tibble(bankrupt = if_else(mtcars$cyl == 8, 1, 0) |> as_factor(),
                        Interest.bearing.dept.interest.rate = mtcars$disp,
                        total_debt_vs_total_net_worth = mtcars$disp,
                        debt_ratio = mtcars$hp)

    debt_split <- initial_split(debt_data, 
                                prop = 3/4)
    debt_split 

    debt_train <- training(debt_split)
    debt_test <- testing(debt_split)

    model1_cv <- vfold_cv(debt_train) # Changed from test

    debt_recipe <- recipe(bankrupt ~
                            Interest.bearing.dept.interest.rate +
                            total_debt_vs_total_net_worth +
                            debt_ratio, 
                          data = debt_data) %>% 
      step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
      step_impute_knn(all_predictors())

    debt_recipe

    logistic_reg_glm_spec <-
      logistic_reg(penalty = 1) |> # randomly chosen penalty
      set_engine('glmnet') |>
      set_mode("classification")

    model_workflow <- workflow() %>%
      add_recipe(debt_recipe) %>%
      add_model(logistic_reg_glm_spec)

    model_workflow

    model_fit <- fit(model_workflow, data = debt_train)

    model_fit <- model_workflow %>% 
      last_fit(debt_split)
    model_fit

    model_performance <- model_fit %>% collect_metrics()
    model_performance
    # Now you get accuracy and roc_auc

    model_predictions <- model_fit %>% collect_predictions()
    model_predictions

    model_predictions |>
    conf_mat(truth = bankrupt,
           estimate = .pred_class)
   ```

You were very close, only three small changes! Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Has that got you past the error Ulrik?